# Core Data iCloud: system shuts down app after consuming too much memory on downloading data from iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

Having a lot of records to download from iCloud makes `addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: options)` to start consuming too much memory.

After a few low memory warnings the system will shut down the app. What can be done to avoid this?

**Later edit**: this happens after console prints "Using local storage: 1 for new NSFileManager current token..." and before "Using storage: 0..."

When pausing the execution, I see this:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that the warnings happen before the call to `addPersistentStoreWithType` finishes?

Comment: @TomHarrington warnings are issued after calling addPSWithType, and while the iCloud data is imported. Thanks